# R or S configuration of propane-1,2-diol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

What is the specific configuration (*R* or *S*) of this compound?

[image: propane-1,2-diol]

My answer is *R*, because $\ce{H}$ is not in the back so I flipped the compound. Is my answer right?

My teacher is telling me it is *S*, though I'm pretty sure that it is *R*. That made me very confused.

What I did is that I got *S* at the beginning, but because $\ce{H}$ is not in the back, I flipped the compound and got the answer *R*. My teacher flipped the compound in a way that the answer was still *S*.

$\ce{OH}$ (1), $\ce{CH2OH}$ (2), $\ce{CH3}$ (3), $\ce{H}$ (4) from 1 to 3, anticlockwise which means it is *S* configuration. But $\ce{H}$ is not in the back, Therefore rotate the compound and the answer should be the opposite to *S* which means it is *R*.

Comment: Well clearly one of you is wrong. Perhaps you could add some diagrams to your question to show what you mean. I have some difficulty in visualising what you are trying to say.

Comment: @saf, here's a hint. The H isn't in the front either...

Comment: Words of caution about flipping structures: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99721/twisting-stereoisomers-with-rings-to-determine-r-s/99750#99750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment is correct where you assign the priority.

Rather than "rotating" or "flipping" the molecule, consider "looking" at it from the angle which makes the H atom be at the back.  In the graphic it is drawn to the left side, so place yourself on the right side and look down the bond.

[image: Annotated original image of propan-1,2-diol]

The priority groups 1-2-3 run anticlockwise, hence it has the S configuration.

Comment: Thank you, I always thought that if number 4 was not in the back, I have to rotate the compound.

Comment: It depends. For example if you swap the H with the CH3 or CH2OH groups, the initial glance of the priorities still looks anticlockwise but when you look down the bond, you see the configuration is actually flipped!