# Why has this molecule a S-chirality?

Tags: chirality

Can someone explain to me, why this molecule has an (S)-chirality? I don't get it. I tried to apply the rules, but I get only an (R)-chirality. Is there something special with cyclo-alkanes?

[image: ethyl (2S)-2-methyloxane-2-carboxylate]

Comment: This is not cycloalkane. It is a cyclicether with ester grop in it at chiral carbon

Comment: Priority is $\ce{-O- \Rightarrow -CO2Et  \Rightarrow  -CH2-  \Rightarrow  -CH3}$

Comment: There is not much to be explained. This molecule is an S enantiomer according to the rules. There are no special rules for cyclic molecules. That's about the size of it.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Thank you for this correction.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I thought all the time, that whenever two carbons have the same priority, it depends on the priority of their substituents. So CH_3 was higher ranked than CH_2 for me.

Comment: Now why would CH3 be ranked higher than CH2, if the latter has some substitute instead of H, which surely has higher priority than H (because _everything_ has higher priority than H)?

Comment: Working outward from the stereocenter, the methylene carbon has its 2 hydrogens and the next carbon in the ring attached to it. This is written as {C,H,H}. The methyl carbon has three hydrogens attached to it. It is designated {H,H,H}. The methylene carbon has priority because a one-to-one comparison has C>H based on atomic number.

Comment: You really don't need the bold and dashed bonds as long as you realize that your ring implies that CH2 is in the foreground and the oxygen is in the rear. If not make the CH2 bond bold and the oxygen bond dashed. Once you establish priorities, don't worry about moving the structure but rather look here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99721/twisting-stereoisomers-with-rings-to-determine-r-s/99750#99750

Answer (score 1):

One subtlety:  when you rank the groups and look at the rotational order of ranks 1, 2, 3, you have to consider also whether group 4 is towards you or away from you.  A clockwise order for 1, 2, 3 (which the given structure shows) corresponds to $R$ when group 4 is directed away from you.  But here group 4 is directed *towards* you, so the chirality is reversed --- 1,2,3 clockwise now means $S$.