# How do I label stereogenic centers R or S when there are 3 bonds in the plane and 1 bond coming out?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I need help with question (d). I labeled the O the first priority, then the C that's bonded to an O the 2nd, and the C above that is attached to 3 other C's the 3rd priority. So, I ended up getting S, but because the 4th priority was not in the back of the plane, I switched it to R. However, this was not the correct answer, as the answer key told me it is actually S.

I'm confused on how to find R or S in this specific type of situation where there are 3 bonds in the plane and 1 bond coming out. Would appreciate help and pointers on where I went wrong. [image]

Comment: Imagine that the bond coming out is actually in the back. That would change the configuration. Now switch the places between OH and the 4th priority. That would change the configuration again.

Comment: Build a 3D model if you can't see the structure around the centre in your head. BTW it is not by any stretch *in the plane*.

Comment: Recognize that carbon "e" lies below the cyclohexene ring.  This post may be of help. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151831/r-or-s-configuration/151842#151842

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign based on the highest priority. After assigning all priorities, if the highest priority group is forward and the direction from 1->2->3 is clockwise, the configuration is R. If counterclockwise, the configuration is S.

In this case, the absolute configuration of **d** is straightforward. You do not switch from S to R because the low priority is not backward. You keep it as S because the highest priority is facing forward.