# Why is the chirality center in (1R, 2S)-2-fluorocyclopentane-1-carboxylic acid 1R and not 1S?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I'm confused why the chirality center in  (*1R, 2S*)-2-fluorocyclopentane-1-carboxylic acid, is *1R* and not *1S*.

[image: (1R, 2S)-2-fluorocyclopentane-1-carboxylic acid]

I'm personally think that the carboxyl carbon at C1 should have a higher priority than the fluoride group at C2 because

- C1 = (C, O, O)
- C2 = (C, F, H)
- C3 = (C, H, H)
- C4 = (H)

So, the priority should go like this C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4. Therefore, I think it should be *1S*. Where do I get wrong?

Comment: F has higher priority than O.

Answer (score 3):

There are two substituted carbon atoms.  Discounting sterochemistry, in the [substitutive nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_nomenclature#Substitutive_nomenclature), the carboxy group has higher priority than the fluorine group. Thus, the framework is 2-fluorocyclopentane-1-carboxylic acid. Then, there is

a) a carbon bound to two other carbons, an hydrogen, and a fluorine.

[image]

Among the atoms around the stereogenic centre, fluorine, with an higher atom number than carbon, has highest priority within the [CIP-rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules) now applied (labeled **1**). Carbon **2** is of higher priority than the one labeled with **3** because (in the next layer), (one carbon and an hydrogen atom) is of higher priority than (two hydrogen atoms).  We observe the substituents from the side opposite to convention, though; thus, the stereogenic centre is (*S*) configured.

b) a carbon bound to three other carbons, and an hydrogen.

[image]

Again, it is the second layer which offers decision about the priorities.  Here, we already observe the stereogenic centre from the convened perspective.  And if we think of the four atoms like a steering wheel, with the atom of lowest priority (here: hydrogen) in the back, it turns to the right hand side; the centre is (*R*).

Thus (1*R*,2*S*)-2-fluorocyclopentane-1-carboxylic acid is the name for the compound.

Note: The site's  compilation [resources for learning chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) has a section dedicated to nomenclature, too.  It equally mentions programs which you may use to draw and assign the CIP labels, too.  Don´t worry, these assignments demand training, training, and training.

Answer (score 3):

@Buttonwood has provided a well-reasoned explanation for the CIP assignments of configuration to fluoro carboxylic acid **A**. While the novice may appreciate why the configuration at C<sub>2</sub> in amino carboxylic acid **B** remains the same as in **A**, the configuration at C<sub>1</sub> in each compound is different even though the two compounds have the same absolute configurations. The reason lies in the fact that the CIP is a construct unrelated to absolute configurations but rather to what is attached to the stereogenic center under consideration.

The digraph illustrates that the first shell around C<sub>1</sub> in **A** is bound to three carbons (C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>5</sub> and C<sub>6</sub>). No decision can be made here! Proceeding to shell 2, C<sub>5</sub> is attached to C<sub>4</sub> and two hydrogens, C<sub>6</sub> is connected to three oxygens and C<sub>2</sub> is attached to a fluorine, carbon and hydrogen. Now these connected atoms are to be ranked in descending order of atomic number, {C,H,H}, {O,O,O} and {F,C,H}, respectively. Here is where the student usually  becomes confused. Now compare the first member in each triad. Because F>O>C, C<sub>1</sub> in **A** has the (*R*)-configuration. Your C<sub>1</sub> (C,O,O) should read (O,O,O). Even so, it would come in second to the triad bearing fluorine. In compound **B**, where nitrogen replaces fluorine, C<sub>1</sub> has the (*S*)-configuration because O>N>C.
You may want to consider [this alternative](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99721/twisting-stereoisomers-with-rings-to-determine-r-s/99750#99750) to the "steering wheel" method for assigning configuration. [This link](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/CIP%20rules%20NEW.html) will help assigning CIP configurations.

[image]